# Where do I position the apostrophe in a plural possessive?

Tags: punctuation

I wanted to write *parents birthdays* but I wasn’t sure whether the apostrophe went before or after the *s* in *parents*. Please explain which is correct and why.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to **write** the phrase. Apostrophes are not present in spoken English, which is one reason why people have trouble with them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use parents (plural) you'd say: "parents' birthdays"

If you want to use parent (singular) you'd say: "parent's birthdays"

Comment: "and why": The possessive form of a word already ending in an s requires that the apostrophe be added *after* that s. If the word has the s due to being a plural, that's the end of the story, but if it's a word that has the s ending in the singular, there's a good deal of disagreement as to whether an additional s should be added after the apostrophe:  "Thomas'[s] doubts about Jesus'[s] resurrection".

Comment: There's no disagreement. A _singular_ word ending is _s_ gets 's, **unless** it's a "high profile" Biblical name: Thomas's, but Jesus'. There seems to be a recent trend to make all names ending in _s_ use just an ' for the possessive, (Thomas'), but that's really not historically proper grammar (even if the AP Style Guide supposedly endorses it). The class's field trip was canceled is an example of non-name usage.

Answer (score 6):

> Parent's birthdays.

The birthdays of a single parent.

> Parents' birthdays.

The birthdays of two or more parents.